# Can we use StAX parser for parsing data using xpaths?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

Can we use a StAX parser for parsing data using paths? why because I think we can't do Stax parser to parse data from xml paths?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html -> **Comparing StAX to Other JAXP APIs** -> XPath Capability

Comment: Without knowing your use case the answer is simply no. XPath expressions usually operate on the whole document. So you need the whole document in memory. You can use a XML database like [BaseX](https://basex.org) for big documents and query them with XQuery which is a superset of XPath. Or you can read the XML using StAX and store the data fields in a relational database like SQLite or PostgreSQL and implement your queries in SQL. There may be thousand other ways depending on your use case.

Comment: @vanje actually we have the whole document in the form of String, need to fetch the required details using XPATHs, but currently, we are experiencing out of memory error, as more  data in memory,  so planning to exploring in StAX whether it will help to handle out of memory issue